# Not able to run SpringBoot 1.5.10.RELEASE on local tomcat(spring boot embedded) server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmx

I have migrated spring application to springBoot1.5.10.RLEASE.

I am getting below error while trying to run application on local server, need help to resolve this error:

> 2018-02-14 18:51:24.173  WARN 12028 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'batchMBeanExporter' defined in class path
>   resource [app-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean
>   'org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean#5287ba5f' of type
>   [org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean] while setting
>   bean property 'jobService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean#5287ba5f':
>   FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'jobService' available

bean creation is still same as it was before springboot migration :-

```
<bean id="batchMBeanExporter" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter">
        <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
        <property name="jobService">
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
                <property name="targetName" value="jobService" />
                <property name="interceptorNames" value="cacheInterceptor" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDomain" value="etl.web.spring.application" />
        <property name="excludedBeans">
        <list>
            <value>integrationMBeanExporter</value>
        </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

----------- update with partial solution -------
below 2 changes solved the problem:-

1. changing version of spring-batch-admin to 1.3.1.RELEASE from 1.2.2.RELEASE
2. and adding jobService bean

but now I am getting below exception, as SimpleEhCacheInterceptor is removed from spring batch admin 1.3.1. any clue on how to replace this property in spring batch admin 1.3.1 version-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.admin.util.SimpleEhCacheInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:401) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1432) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1377) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Bean for cachInterceptor-

```
<bean id="cacheInterceptor" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.util.SimpleEhCacheInterceptor" >
        <property name="cacheName" value="webSimple_${env}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: it is telling you that there is no bean named "jobService" that you are setting as a property on the proxyFactoryBean.

So my question is, have you defined a bean named "JobService" in the spring context that spring can use and autowire.

Comment: so we did not create JobService bean in the spring context before migration.
do we need to explicitly create the bean for the same in springboot?

Comment: i don't know what it is you are trying to do. All i can tell you is that the exception is telling you that when it is trying to autowire in something called JobService it can't find it.

And i have no idea what you have done "before" and how it found it "before".

Answer (score 1):

```
Now I am able to start the server without any of the above mentioned issues.

SimpleEhCacheInterceptor is removed from version 1.3.0 to remove explicit caching instead caching is implemented internally in version 1.3.0 of spring batch admin manager. JIRA for the same  https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCHADM-133

After removing cacheInterceptor, application was throwing below issue-
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchMBeanExporter' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean#4ae2e781' of type [org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'jobService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean#4ae2e781': Post-processing of FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Need to invoke method 'removeInactiveExecutions' declared on target class 'SimpleJobService', but not found in any interface(s) of the exposed proxy type. Either pull the method up to an interface or switch to CGLIB proxies by enforcing proxy-target-class mode in your configuration.

have set the proxyTargetClass property to true, now the embedded tomcat with spring boot is starting up without any issue.
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin-samples/issues/12
    Spring doc - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types
    JIRA for the same - https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCHADM-126

```
working configuration:-
Spring batch admin manager version 1.3.1

    <bean id="batchMBeanExporter" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter">
        <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
        <property name="jobService">
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
                <property name="targetName" value="jobService" />
                <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDomain" value="spring.application" />
    </bean>

<bean id="jobService" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.service.SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
    <property name="jobLocator" ref="jobRegistry"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... It got me past the exception..I was getting below error in my spring boot app(@EnableScheduling) +Spring Batch Admin            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Need to invoke method 'removeInactiveExecutions' declared on target class 'SimpleJobService', but not found in any interface(s) of the exposed proxy type. Either pull the method up to an interface or switch to CGLIB proxies by enforcing proxy-target-class mode in your configuration.

Comment: Glad that the answer is helpful.